# вопрос python(ошибка библиотеки pikepdf)

Tags: python-3.x, pip

При установке  библиотеки pikepdf из cmd вылетает такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю как исправить.

Comment: Ну почему-то файл `qpdf/Constants.h` найти не может

Comment: я уже переустанавливал python  не помогло

Comment: А проблема не в питоне, а именно в этой библиотеке